# Doctrine Get list of all Models

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, zend-loader

I want to get list of all my Doctrine Models. Someone know how to do ?

Thank's

Answer (score 3):

```
Doctrine_Core::getLoadedModels()
```